# How do I add variables to be set based on a numeric input in perl?

Tags: perl

I am making a score-keeping script in Perl, and would like to have it ask how many players there are, and ask for a name, then score, for each player. I have a good bit of this script done, but only for 3 players. the current script can be found on github here: [skore](https://github.com/vaaz420/skore)

(from link:)

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
my $version = "1.0";
my $arg = shift(@ARGV);
my $subname = $arg;
if (!defined($arg)){
    cmd_go();
}
$subname =~ s/-/_/g;
my $sub = main->can("cmd_$subname") || main->can("dev_$subname") || main->can("hid_$subname");
if (!defined($sub))
{
    print STDERR "Invalid command given.\nUse \e[1;32m./skore help\e[0m for a list of commands.\n";
    exit 1;
}
else
{
    $sub->(@ARGV);
    exit 0;
}
# Main command
sub cmd_go()
{
    print "\e[2J\e[0G\e[0d"; # J = Erase in Display, 2 = Entire Screen, (G, d) = Move cursor to (..,..)
    print "••••••••••••••••••••\n";
    print "• Welcome to \e[1;32mskore\e[0m •\n";
    print "••••••••••••••••••••\n\n";
    my @game = prompt("What game are we scoring?\n");
    print "••• Game name locked: @game\n\n";
    my @p1name = prompt("Player 1 name?\n");
    my @p2name = prompt("Player 2 name?\n");
    my @p3name = prompt("Player 3 name?\n");
    print "\n";
    print "••• Player names locked: @p1name @p2name @p3name\n\n";
    my @p1score = prompt_num("score for @p1name?\n");
    my @p2score = prompt_num("score for @p2name?\n");
    my @p3score = prompt_num("score for @p3name?\n");
    print "\n";
    print "••• Game: @game\n";
    print "••• @p1name\n";
    print "••••• \e[1;32m@p1score\e[0m\n";
    print "••• @p2name\n";
    print "••••• \e[1;32m@p2score\e[0m\n";
    print "••• @p3name\n";
    print "••••• \e[1;32m@p3score\e[0m\n";
    exit 1;
}
sub cmd_help()
{
    print "To get right into using skore, simply type ./skore\n";
    print "For details about skore, such as version, use ./skore pkg\n";
}
sub cmd_pkg()
{
    print "skore version: $version\n";
    print "Detected OS: ";
    exec "uname -r";
}

sub prompt {
    my ($query) = @_; # take a prompt string as argument
    local $| = 1; # activate autoflush to immediately show the prompt 
    print $query;
    chomp(my $answer = <STDIN>); return $answer;
}
sub prompt_num {
    NSTART:
    my ($querynum) = @_;
    print $querynum;
    chomp(my $pnum = <STDIN>);
    if ($pnum eq $pnum+0) { return $pnum; }
    else { print "Error: That is not a number. Try again.\n"; goto NSTART; }
}
sub prompt_yn {
    my ($queryyn) = @_;
    my $answer = prompt("$queryyn (y/N): ");
    return lc($answer) eq 'y';
}
```

I'd like to also point out that I'm new to perl.

Comment: Learn arrays. Instead of a variable for each player and score you will have an array of player names and another one for scores. Like:

my @players; my $p=5 /* example, player 5 */; $players[$p] = prompt("Player $p name: ")

Later on will may learn about more complex data structures where you store everything behind a single named variable Like: $player[5]->{score}

Comment: Hello. Here at stack overflow, we don't like offsite links that are essential to the question. Referencing a source is fine, but the question (or answer) should be self contained. Please see [ask] for what makes a good question. I would also note - you specifically should also be specific about a problem you're having with code.

Answer (score -4, accepted):

Try this. Hope this is what you wanted.

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
my $version = "1.0";
my $arg = shift(@ARGV);
my $subname = $arg;
if (!defined($arg)){
    cmd_go();
}
$subname =~ s/-/_/g;
my $sub = main->can("cmd_$subname") || main->can("dev_$subname") || main->can("hid_$subname");
if (!defined($sub))
{
    print STDERR "Invalid command given.\nUse \e[1;32m./skore help\e[0m for a list of commands.\n";
    exit 1;
}
else
{
    $sub->(@ARGV);
    exit 0;
}
# Main command
sub cmd_go()
{
    print "\e[2J\e[0G\e[0d"; # J = Erase in Display, 2 = Entire Screen, (G, d) = Move cursor to (..,..)
    print "••••••••••••••••••••\n";
    print "• Welcome to \e[1;32mskore\e[0m •\n";
    print "••••••••••••••••••••\n\n";
    my @game = prompt("What game are we scoring?\n");
    print "••• Game name locked: @game\n\n";
    my $players= prompt("Enter total number of players:\n");
    my @players_list;
    for(my $i=0;$i<$players;$i++){
            push(@players_list , prompt("Enter Player ".($i+1)." name\n"));
    }
    print "\n";
            print "••• Player names locked:  ";
    for(my $i=0;$i<$players;$i++){
            print $players_list[$i]."\t";
    }
    print "\n\n";
    my @players_score;
    for(my $i=0;$i<$players;$i++){
            push(@players_score, prompt("score for $players_list[$i]?\n"));
    }
    print "\n";
    print "••• Game: @game\n";
    for(my $i=0;$i<$players;$i++){
            print "$players_list[$i]\n";
            print "••••• \e[1;32m$players_score[$i]\e[0m\n";
    }
    exit 1;
}
sub cmd_help()
{
    print "To get right into using skore, simply type ./skore\n";
    print "For details about skore, such as version, use ./skore pkg\n";
}
sub cmd_pkg()
{
    print "skore version: $version\n";
    print "Detected OS: ";
    exec "uname -r";
}
sub prompt {
    my ($query) = @_; # take a prompt string as argument
    local $| = 1; # activate autoflush to immediately show the prompt 
    print $query;
    chomp(my $answer = <STDIN>); return $answer;
}
sub prompt_num {
    NSTART:
    my ($querynum) = @_;
    print $querynum;
    chomp(my $pnum = <STDIN>);
    if ($pnum eq $pnum+0) { return $pnum; }
    else { print "Error: That is not a number. Try again.\n"; goto NSTART; }
}
sub prompt_yn {
    my ($queryyn) = @_;
    my $answer = prompt("$queryyn (y/N): ");
    return lc($answer) eq 'y';
}
```

Answer (score 6):

OK, wow. Stop for a moment, step back and put the code down. Think about what you're trying to accomplish here.

There's a bunch of things you're doing in your code that's really going to benefit from taking a step back, and understanding what's going on, before proceeding.

First off:

```
my $arg = shift(@ARGV);
my $subname = $arg;
if (!defined($arg)){
    cmd_go();
}
```

What is this intended to do? You only use `$arg` 3 times here, and one of those is to copy it to `$subname`.

This could be quite simplified by:

```
my $subname = shift; 
cmd_go() unless defined $subname;
```

Now this:

```
my $sub = main->can("cmd_$subname") || main->can("dev_$subname") || main->can("hid_$subname");
```

Where did that come from? Because I'm pretty sure that - as a beginner to perl - you didn't write that yourself, not least because you don't have any subroutines prefixed with `dev_` or `hid`. And this sort of redirect is serious overkill for a program that basically does just one thing.

(And normally, you'd use flags like `getopt` rather than a command that you leave blank in a default state).

You are also massively overusing arrays - which suggests you're not really sure the difference between `@game` and `$game`.

E.g. this:

```
    my @game = prompt("What game are we scoring?\n");
```

`prompt` does this though:

```
chomp(my $answer = <STDIN>); return $answer;
```

It returns a scalar (a single line) and you're putting it into an array for - as far as I can tell - no particular reason.

Likewise this:

```
my @p1score = prompt_num("score for @p1name?\n");
my @p2score = prompt_num("score for @p2name?\n");
my @p3score = prompt_num("score for @p3name?\n");
```

First off - you're using a bunch of single element arrays. But then you're numbering them. When ... actually, the whole point of arrays is to have numbered values.

So how about instead:

```
print "Num players?:\n";
chomp ( my $num = <STDIN> );
my @players;
my %scores; 
for ( 1..$num ) {
     print "Player name\n";
     chomp ( my $name = <STDIN> ); 
     push ( @players, $name ); 
}

foreach my $person ( @players )  {
    print "Score for $person:\n"; 
    chomp ( my $score = <STDIN> ); 
    while ( $score =~ /\D/ ) { 
        print "Invalid - please enter numeric value\n";
        chomp ( $score = <STDIN> ); 
    }
    $scores{$person} = $score; 
}

foreach my $person ( @players ) { 
    print "$person => $score{$person}\n";
}
```

There are a bunch of other things that you're doing that is more complicated than it needs to be.

What I would suggest you do:

- go re-read the perl basics. [`perldata`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perldata.html)  in particular.
- have a look at [`getopt`](http://perldoc.perl.org/Getopt/Std.html) which is a good (and standard) way to take program 'flag' style input. (e.g. showing version, if that's what you really want.
- it looks a lot like you've cargo-culted the code here. I would suggest you re-write from the ground up, and when you hit a problem - ask about it on Stack Overflow, if you can't figure it out from the perl docs.